# CSS required to make lightning:checkboxGroup items display horizontally

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, checkbox

What CSS would be required to make the items in a lightning:checkboxGroup display horizontally rather than the default of vertical?

Comment: what have you tried so far?? 
using some CSS you can change the appearance as per your requirement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS required to make the checkbox options display horizontally rather than vertically:

```
.THIS .slds-checkbox {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

To be added to the lightning component CSS

Note, you can achieve the same thing for radio button options using:

```
.THIS .slds-radio {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/salesforce- lightning-design-system.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<span class="slds-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="checkbox-2" value="checkbox-2" />
         <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="checkbox-2">
            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">Checkbox Check-1</span>
    </label>


    <input type="checkbox" name="options1" id="checkbox-3" value="checkbox-3" />
    <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="checkbox-3">
            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">Checkbox Check-2</span>
        </label>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are we supposed to 'use' this code? It would be much better to paste the code here; make sure to indent it by 4 spaces to make sure it's readable (hit Ctrl + K or the 'Code Sample' button in the editor).

Comment: Does it resolve your issue?

Comment: Thank you! It would be even better with some explanation and a screenshot :)

Comment: I asked for CSS not HTML. This answer does not help, please delete.